# Edit of Row in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have table which looks  like this:

| ID | NameOfProduct | Quantity | Price1 in USD | Price 2 in USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Energy | 5 | 3,5 | 2,7 |
| 2 | Gas | 10 | 3 | 21,2 |

Then I created form based on this table, which is a Splitform. I want to create a button which would allow me to create a correction of chosen row.

It should create another row with negative values of the corrected row (only the columns which are numeric), because I don't want to erase the row, I need the evidence for later how the original row looked like and then it would allow me to edit values of selected row and add it into the table as another row

I have no idea how to even start with this - If I can do this by only using macros, or SQL or do I need to use VBA?

Please help!

Comment: You need to duplicate record then edit. But in this case you can not see history which row was edited. You need a separate table to keep log (insert previous record ID by button click) then new record ID so that you can identify which record was edited.

Comment: Question was already asked, commented, closed and then apparently deleted. Same comments apply.

Comment: @June7 Yes, it was closed but without my "consent" so I deleted that one and asked again

Comment: Closing doesn't need author's consent. Your question is not different and likely to be closed again. Did you even consider the comments provided?

Comment: @June7 yes, I tried implementing some solutions, but it didn't work exactly as I wanted so that's why I posted it again.

Comment: So add the attempted code in question and describe what happened, why it did not meet your needs. In other words, ask a new question, not the same one. As is, comments provided before still apply.